# Maven: Build code against Java 1.4, but build test code against Java 1.5

Tags: java, maven

In Maven, I have a codebase that I want to build that needs to target the 1.4 JVM. This is very easy to do in the pom, but I have one problem: The tests for this codebase use 1.5+ constructs.

Is it possible to have Maven compile/run the tests inside a 1.6 JVM, but build the main codebase to target 1.4?

Setting source to 1.6 and target to 1.4 don't work. Maven/Java don't allow this combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I wanted with this:

```
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <testSource>1.6</testSource>
            <testTarget>1.6</testTarget>
            <target>1.4</target>
            <source>1.4</source>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but you need to set the parameters for [testCompile](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/testCompile-mojo.html) rather than [compile](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html). You can specify a different target/source combination for the testCompile that you use for the compile.

So for compile you've have a target of 1.4, and testCompile 1.5 or 1.6.

Also, to run the unit tests, you can specify the jvm to use in surefire by using the [jvm](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#jvm) parameter. This would point to a 1.6 jvm.

Answer (score 1):

It's been awhile since I've done this, but the plugin dependency you want is something like this:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default-compile</id>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.3</source>
        <target>1.3</target>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>default-testCompile</id>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.5</source>
        <target>1.5</target>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

[link to source](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-default-execution-ids.html#Example%3a_Configuring_compile_and_testCompile_mojos_separately)